# Is it possible to create a backbone collection view without Collection instance

Tags: backbone.js

I am new to backbonejs and I cannot find answer to my query in backbone docs.

I'd like to create CollectionView and use as part of other view without collection and wondering if its possible.

Comment: view as part of collection? model is a part of collection. What u going to reach ?

Comment: There is a model and its respective view, this mentioned model is collection of some views, those views will be a collection of view which I want to make

Comment: "model is collection of views" ? very weird. Title of the question is clear - yes, u can create view without model or collection. But "collection of views".. maybe you mean Collection View (rendering set of models delegating render action to the model view) ? If so, then you will have to use collection to iterate over or think about custom iteration

Comment: Sorry for bad explanation from my part, I meant Collection view only. Although you understood my problem and comment given by you pretty much answers my query. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is **No**

Standard Collection View work flow:

Collection view iterate over collection. On every iteration instancing new ModelView and provide iteration model as data and delegate render to ModelView instance. ModelView instance render data and keeps template.

So u have to keep collection to iterate with of replace it with something else to iterate with.